# python classifier different parameters using **kwargs

Tags: python, optimization, keyword-argument

I want to make my code more pythonic, or more optimized and I am stuck. After day wrapping my head around to find out how to use **kwargs properly I was able  to use them in my function (train_logreg). 
When I directly pass parametrs to train_logreg function:

```
model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0)
```

It's working as expected. However I want automize changing parameters [solver, penalty, C]. Can you help me?
Below you find the code:

```py
def train_logreg(X_train_sc, y_train, **kwargs):
    clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, 
                             class_weight='balanced',
                             solver=kwargs.get('solver', 'sag'),
                             penalty=kwargs.get('penalty', 'l2'), 
                             C=kwargs.get('C', 1.0))
    model = clf.fit(X_train_sc, y_train)
    return model 

def eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test):
    return model.score(X_test_sc, y_test)

scores = []

for hyperparameters in [{'train_function':train_logreg}]:
    train = hyperparameters.get('train_function')
    model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0)
    scores.append(["solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0",eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test), eval_model(X_train_sc, y_train)])
    model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=0.5)
    scores.append(["solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=0.5",eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test), eval_model(X_train_sc, y_train)])
    model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=0.1)
    scores.append(["solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=0.1",eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test), eval_model(X_train_sc, y_train)])
    model = train(X_train_sc, y_train)
    scores.append(["default",eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test), eval_model(X_train_sc, y_train)])

scores
```

Comment: can you state what the issue is clearly?

Comment: The last part of the code:
```
for hyperparameters in [{'train_function':train_logreg}]:
    train = hyperparameters.get('train_function')
    model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0)
    scores.append(["solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0",eval_model(X_test_sc, y_test), eval_model(X_train_sc, y_train)])
```
I don't want setting 'model' each time manually, but have it more automatized. Is this clearer?

Comment: thats not stating the issue? what's wrong with it, is it breaking or what? please be thorough in your explanation

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment (hitting enter instead shift+enter).

Comment: you mean supplying the keyword arguments every time you call your function?

Comment: Yes. instead of 'model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, solver='liblinear', penalty='l1', C=1.0)' having smt like model = train(X_train_sc, y_train, kwargs) and kwargs will be different each iteration (and be printed)

Comment: if the kwargs are different every iteration you’ll have to change it every time regardless